# How do I disable a Sharepoint Web Part without being on the exact page?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Alright, so in my SharePoint (2013) site, I made a simple JavaScript Web Part to refresh the page every five minutes.  I went to adjust the time, backspaced out where I'd entered the time to wait before a refresh, and without thinking exited the edit page.  This left me in an infinite loop of refresh, and since I do not have admin access to the laptop I am working on, I cannot manually disable JavaScript.  My hope now is to find a way to edit, or just delete, the Web Part causing this from elsewhere.  Can this be done?

Here's the code I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var reloadTimer = null;
var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);

function setReloadTime(secs)
{ if (arguments.length == 1)
   { if (reloadTimer) clearTimeout(reloadTimer);
       reloadTimer = setTimeout("setReloadTime()", Math.ceil(parseFloat    (secs)*1000));
   }
   else
   { reloadTimer = null;
     location.reload(true);
     window.location.replace( sURL );
   }
}

setReloadTime(); //Here was where I had 300
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter Contents=1 to URL of the webpart page. It displays page in setup mode allowing you to remove webpart from the page. The final URL will look like this http://portal.contoso.com/page.aspx?Contents=1